# Do not want to show Tooltipster on Windows Phone

Tags: windows-phone, tooltipster

I am using `Tooltipster` to show popup on my website. I do not want this tooltip to show on touch devices, so i use the option - `touchDevices: false`. It is working fine on all other touch devices except Windows Phone. Any suggestions, how can I resolve this.

Thanks

Comment: Less of an answer and more of a question to a question, but do you have the ability to debug using Web Developer tools on your Windows Phone? The reason I ask is that Tooltipster uses it's on in-built functions to determine if the device is "touch capable" or if the "device has a mouse" via `deviceIsPureTouch()`. I suggest console logging out these values in the unminified version of Tooltipster to see if you can gauge if it's doing what it says on the tin. Hope this helps :)